# Linq with entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to LINQ and Entity Framework and would appreciate some advice on the following scenario.

I have a entity model with two tables.

Travel_Request and Resource

**Sample Fields**

Travel_Request

```
Request_ID
Resource_ID
```

Resource

```
Resource_ID
Resource_Name
```

I would like to add the Resource_Name to the list when returning all the TRAVEL_REQUESTS

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the query you are using to get all Travel_Requests and then, if you can, show us a query you've tried to get Resource.Resource_Name. More often than not, that excercise will make you discover the answer. Also, it would be nice to know if you have an association setup in your database between those tables.

Comment: You wouldn't normally do this - you would more normally have a navigation property from Travel_Request pointing at the Request directly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi you need to use the Linq join:

```
var data = from t in Travel_Request
       join r in Resource on t.Resource_ID equals r.Resource_ID
       select new 
              { 
                 RequestId = t.Request_ID,
                 ResourceId = t.Resource_ID,
                 ResourceName = r.Resource_Name
              };
```

If you already have an EF association then it could simply be:

```
var data = from t in Travel_Request
    select new
           {
                 RequestId = t.Request_ID,
                 ResourceId = t.Resource_ID,
                 ResourceName = t.Resource.Resource_Name
           };
```

Comment: What if he already has an association setup in you database between the Resource_Ids in the two tables?

Comment: Then it could be simplified: var data = from t in Travel_Request select new { RequestId = t.Request_ID, ResourceId = t.Resource_ID, ResourceName = t.Resource.Resource_Name }

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new object something like this.

```
var data = Travel_Request.Select(s=> new { Resource_Name = s.Recource.Resource_Name, Request_ID = s.Request_ID, Resource_ID = s.Resource_ID}).ToList();
```

As long as I've understood the question correctly this will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can query Travel_Request entity and use the navigation propety to do that.

```
var resultList = DbContext.Travel_Request.Resources.where(x=>x.Resource_Name =="Your string").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Join:

```
Travel_Request.Join(Resource, tr => tr.ResourceId, r => r.ResourceId, (tr, r) => new { RequestId = tr.RequestId, ResourceId = tr.ResourceId, Name = r.ResourceName})
```

Or what a better practice would be is adding a Navigation property to TravelRequest.
TravelRequest would look like this:

```
int RequestId { get; set; }
int ResourceId{ get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ResourceId")]
Resource Resource { get; set; }
```

This way you can use Include

```
DBContext.TravelRequests.Include("Resource").First().Resource.Name;
```

Include tells EF to get the Resource with the TravelerRequest

Answer (score 1):

I would add a model that has all three then do something like.

```
var TravelRequests = 
    from p in Travel_Request
from r in Resource.where(Res => Res.Resource_ID == p.Resource_ID)
    select new TravelModel{
requestID = p.requestID,
Resource_ID = p.Resource_ID,
ResourceName = r.ResourceName

};
```

But thats just an example of how I would do it and there might be better ways. Also syntax might be a little off but general idea is there.